# Knockout not respecting $index binding context

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have a foreach binding where I don't want to display a checkbox if it is the first row:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items" class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="if: $index() > 0,checked: $data.isChecked, click: $parent.removeRow">
  </div>
  <!-- other cols -->
</div>
```

However, the checkbox is being displayed for each row.

Comment: what about no parens - `if: $index > 0`

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: try putting `if` in quotes

Comment: what if you wrap with a div and use the `data-bind:if` directive alone?

Comment: That works, but why doesn't it work on the input element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The if binding causes a section of markup to appear in your document
>   (and to have its data-bind attributes applied), only if a specified
>   expression evaluates to true (or a true-ish value such as a non-null
>   object or nonempty string).

([source](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html))

`data-bind: if` directive will remove **the content**  of the tag you are applying the directive to. Wrapping your input in a div will do the trick:

```
<div cata-bind="if: $index() > 0">
     <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $data.isChecked, click: $parent.removeRow">
</div>
```